# dropdown button in input-group-btn is cut off on right border

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, button, input, drop-down-menu

I just started to play around with bootstrap (I am totally new to this web development at all) and managed to combine a dropdown menu with a text input.

However, the button is somehow cut off on the right border. It seems that there is not enough space for the text input and the combined button.

See last part of my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Parameter</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here...">
            <span class="input-group-addon">kg</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Parameter</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here...">
            <span class="input-group-addon">km/h</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select from dropdown...">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn form-control input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Sorry for the "How does this work? What am I doing wrong?"-kind of question. I am using Firefox on MacOS.

Comment: you added caret outside the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't mix with other components Do not mix form groups or grid column
>   classes directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input group
>   inside of the form group or grid-related element. You're mixing
>   classes that shouldn't be mixed together.

This

```
 <button type="button" class="btn form-control input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
```

Should be something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span> </button>
```

This

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
```

Should be.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
```

Just use CSS to make the add-ons the same color. I also wouldn't mix `columns` within an `input-group` class. See the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

*I changed the column size for the inputs for this example, they can easily be changed back or to whatever you want.

See working Snippet.

```css
.btn.btn-drop {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parameter</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here..."> <span class="input-group-addon">kg</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parameter</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here..."> <span class="input-group-addon">km/h</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select from dropdown...">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-drop dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 3</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Parameter</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here...">
            <span class="input-group-addon">kg</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Parameter</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value here...">
            <span class="input-group-addon">km/h</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5zd2vk9c/4/)